# GIFEncoder.Class.php and a no loop GIF animation

Tags: animation, loops, encoding, gif

I'm using the GIFEncoderclass to convert a series of GIF images to an animated Gif.

What I am trying to do is set the loop so that it doesnt repeat.

When I set loop to 1, in Chrome and IE it doesnt play once... but loops once (so plays twice). In FireFox though it works as intended, plays one doesn't loop.

Is this a bug in the GIFEncoder?

Am i doing something wrong?

And how do i solve this?

my Code

```
$gif = new GIFEncoder   (
                            $frames, // frames array
                            $time, // elapsed time array
                            1, // loops (0 = infinite)
                            0, // disposal
                            3, 2, 1,
                            0,// rgb of transparency
                            "url" // source type
        );
```

GIFEncoder class

```
Class GIFEncoder {
    var $GIF = "GIF89a";            /* GIF header 6 bytes   */
    var $VER = "GIFEncoder V3.00";  /* Encoder version              */

    var $BUF = Array ( );
    var $OFS = Array ( );
    var $SIG =  0;
    var $LOP =  0;
    var $DIS =  2;
    var $COL = -1;
    var $IMG = -1;

    var $ERR = Array (
            'ERR00'=>"Does not supported function for only one image!",
            'ERR01'=>"Source is not a GIF image!",
            'ERR02'=>"Unintelligible flag ",
            'ERR03'=>"Does not make animation from animated GIF source",
    );

    /*
    :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    ::
    ::      GIFEncoder...
    ::
    */
    function GIFEncoder     (
                                                    $GIF_src, $GIF_dly, $GIF_lop, $GIF_dis,
                                                    $GIF_red, $GIF_grn, $GIF_blu, $GIF_ofs,
                                                    $GIF_mod
                                            ) {
            if ( ! is_array ( $GIF_src ) && ! is_array ( $GIF_dly ) ) {
                    printf  ( "%s: %s", $this->VER, $this->ERR [ 'ERR00' ] );
                    exit    ( 0 );
            }
            if ( is_array ( $GIF_ofs ) && count ( $GIF_ofs ) > 1 ) {
                    $this->SIG = 1;
                    $this->OFS = $GIF_ofs;
            }
            $this->LOP = $GIF_lop === false ? false : (( $GIF_lop > -1 ) ? $GIF_lop : 0);
            $this->DIS = ( $GIF_dis > -1 ) ? ( ( $GIF_dis < 3 ) ? $GIF_dis : 3 ) : 2;
            $this->COL = ( $GIF_red > -1 && $GIF_grn > -1 && $GIF_blu > -1 ) ?
                                            ( $GIF_red | ( $GIF_grn << 8 ) | ( $GIF_blu << 16 ) ) : -1;

            for ( $i = 0; $i < count ( $GIF_src ); $i++ ) {
                    if ( strToLower ( $GIF_mod ) == "url" ) {
                            $this->BUF [ ] = fread ( fopen ( $GIF_src [ $i ], "rb" ), filesize ( $GIF_src [ $i ] ) );
                    }
                    else if ( strToLower ( $GIF_mod ) == "bin" ) {
                            $this->BUF [ ] = $GIF_src [ $i ];
                    }
                    else {
                            printf  ( "%s: %s ( %s )!", $this->VER, $this->ERR [ 'ERR02' ], $GIF_mod );
                            exit    ( 0 );
                    }
                    if ( substr ( $this->BUF [ $i ], 0, 6 ) != "GIF87a" && substr ( $this->BUF [ $i ], 0, 6 ) != "GIF89a" ) {
                            printf  ( "%s: %d %s", $this->VER, $i, $this->ERR [ 'ERR01' ] );
                            exit    ( 0 );
                    }
                    for ( $j = ( 13 + 3 * ( 2 << ( ord ( $this->BUF [ $i ] { 10 } ) & 0x07 ) ) ), $k = TRUE; $k; $j++ ) {
                            switch ( $this->BUF [ $i ] { $j } ) {
                                    case "!":
                                            if ( ( substr ( $this->BUF [ $i ], ( $j + 3 ), 8 ) ) == "NETSCAPE" ) {
                                                    printf  ( "%s: %s ( %s source )!", $this->VER, $this->ERR [ 'ERR03' ], ( $i + 1 ) );
                                                    exit    ( 0 );
                                            }
                                            break;
                                    case ";":
                                            $k = FALSE;
                                            break;
                            }
                    }
            }
            GIFEncoder::GIFAddHeader ( );
            for ( $i = 0; $i < count ( $this->BUF ); $i++ ) {
                    GIFEncoder::GIFAddFrames ( $i, $GIF_dly [ $i ] );
            }
            GIFEncoder::GIFAddFooter ( );
    }
    /*
    :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    ::
    ::      GIFAddHeader...
    ::
    */
    function GIFAddHeader ( ) {
            $cmap = 0;

            if ( ord ( $this->BUF [ 0 ] { 10 } ) & 0x80 ) {
                    $cmap = 3 * ( 2 << ( ord ( $this->BUF [ 0 ] { 10 } ) & 0x07 ) );

                    $this->GIF .= substr ( $this->BUF [ 0 ], 6, 7           );
                    $this->GIF .= substr ( $this->BUF [ 0 ], 13, $cmap      );

                    if($this->LOP !== false)
                    {

                            $this->GIF .= "!\377\13NETSCAPE2.0\3\1" . GIFEncoder::GIFWord ( $this->LOP ) . "\0";
                    }
            }
    }
    /*
    :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    ::
    ::      GIFAddFrames...
    ::
    */
    function GIFAddFrames ( $i, $d ) {

            $Locals_str = 13 + 3 * ( 2 << ( ord ( $this->BUF [ $i ] { 10 } ) & 0x07 ) );

            $Locals_end = strlen ( $this->BUF [ $i ] ) - $Locals_str - 1;
            $Locals_tmp = substr ( $this->BUF [ $i ], $Locals_str, $Locals_end );

            $Global_len = 2 << ( ord ( $this->BUF [ 0  ] { 10 } ) & 0x07 );
            $Locals_len = 2 << ( ord ( $this->BUF [ $i ] { 10 } ) & 0x07 );

            $Global_rgb = substr ( $this->BUF [ 0  ], 13,
                                                    3 * ( 2 << ( ord ( $this->BUF [ 0  ] { 10 } ) & 0x07 ) ) );
            $Locals_rgb = substr ( $this->BUF [ $i ], 13,
                                                    3 * ( 2 << ( ord ( $this->BUF [ $i ] { 10 } ) & 0x07 ) ) );

            $Locals_ext = "!\xF9\x04" . chr ( ( $this->DIS << 2 ) + 0 ) .
                                            chr ( ( $d >> 0 ) & 0xFF ) . chr ( ( $d >> 8 ) & 0xFF ) . "\x0\x0";

            if ( $this->COL > -1 && ord ( $this->BUF [ $i ] { 10 } ) & 0x80 ) {
                    for ( $j = 0; $j < ( 2 << ( ord ( $this->BUF [ $i ] { 10 } ) & 0x07 ) ); $j++ ) {
                            if      (
                                            ord ( $Locals_rgb { 3 * $j + 0 } ) == ( ( $this->COL >> 16 ) & 0xFF ) &&
                                            ord ( $Locals_rgb { 3 * $j + 1 } ) == ( ( $this->COL >>  8 ) & 0xFF ) &&
                                            ord ( $Locals_rgb { 3 * $j + 2 } ) == ( ( $this->COL >>  0 ) & 0xFF )
                                    ) {
                                    $Locals_ext = "!\xF9\x04" . chr ( ( $this->DIS << 2 ) + 1 ) .
                                                                    chr ( ( $d >> 0 ) & 0xFF ) . chr ( ( $d >> 8 ) & 0xFF ) . chr ( $j ) . "\x0";
                                    break;
                            }
                    }
            }
            switch ( $Locals_tmp { 0 } ) {
                    case "!":
                            $Locals_img = substr ( $Locals_tmp, 8, 10 );
                            $Locals_tmp = substr ( $Locals_tmp, 18, strlen ( $Locals_tmp ) - 18 );
                            break;
                    case ",":
                            $Locals_img = substr ( $Locals_tmp, 0, 10 );
                            $Locals_tmp = substr ( $Locals_tmp, 10, strlen ( $Locals_tmp ) - 10 );
                            break;
            }
            if ( ord ( $this->BUF [ $i ] { 10 } ) & 0x80 && $this->IMG > -1 ) {
                    if ( $Global_len == $Locals_len ) {
                            if ( GIFEncoder::GIFBlockCompare ( $Global_rgb, $Locals_rgb, $Global_len ) ) {
                                    $this->GIF .= ( $Locals_ext . $Locals_img . $Locals_tmp );
                            }
                            else {
                                    /*
                                     *
                                     * XY Padding...
                                     *
                                     */
                                    if ( $this->SIG == 1 ) {
                                            $Locals_img { 1 } = chr ( $this->OFS [ $i ] [ 0 ] & 0xFF );
                                            $Locals_img { 2 } = chr ( ( $$this->OFS [ $i ] [ 0 ] & 0xFF00 ) >> 8 );
                                            $Locals_img { 3 } = chr ( $this->OFS [ $i ] [ 1 ] & 0xFF );
                                            $Locals_img { 4 } = chr ( ( $this->OFS [ $i ] [ 1 ] & 0xFF00 ) >> 8 );
                                    }
                                    $byte  = ord ( $Locals_img { 9 } );
                                    $byte |= 0x80;
                                    $byte &= 0xF8;
                                    $byte |= ( ord ( $this->BUF [ 0 ] { 10 } ) & 0x07 );
                                    $Locals_img { 9 } = chr ( $byte );
                                    $this->GIF .= ( $Locals_ext . $Locals_img . $Locals_rgb . $Locals_tmp );
                            }
                    }
                    else {
                            /*
                             *
                             * XY Padding...
                             *
                             */
                            if ( $this->SIG == 1 ) {
                                    $Locals_img { 1 } = chr ( $this->OFS [ $i ] [ 0 ] & 0xFF );
                                    $Locals_img { 2 } = chr ( ( $$this->OFS [ $i ] [ 0 ] & 0xFF00 ) >> 8 );
                                    $Locals_img { 3 } = chr ( $this->OFS [ $i ] [ 1 ] & 0xFF );
                                    $Locals_img { 4 } = chr ( ( $this->OFS [ $i ] [ 1 ] & 0xFF00 ) >> 8 );
                            }
                            $byte  = ord ( $Locals_img { 9 } );
                            $byte |= 0x80;
                            $byte &= 0xF8;
                            $byte |= ( ord ( $this->BUF [ $i ] { 10 } ) & 0x07 );
                            $Locals_img { 9 } = chr ( $byte );
                            $this->GIF .= ( $Locals_ext . $Locals_img . $Locals_rgb . $Locals_tmp );
                    }
            }
            else {
                    $this->GIF .= ( $Locals_ext . $Locals_img . $Locals_tmp );
            }
            $this->IMG  = 1;
    }
    /*
    :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    ::
    ::      GIFAddFooter...
    ::
    */
    function GIFAddFooter ( ) {
            $this->GIF .= ";";
    }
    /*
    :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    ::
    ::      GIFBlockCompare...
    ::
    */
    function GIFBlockCompare ( $GlobalBlock, $LocalBlock, $Len ) {

            for ( $i = 0; $i < $Len; $i++ ) {
                    if      (
                                    $GlobalBlock { 3 * $i + 0 } != $LocalBlock { 3 * $i + 0 } ||
                                    $GlobalBlock { 3 * $i + 1 } != $LocalBlock { 3 * $i + 1 } ||
                                    $GlobalBlock { 3 * $i + 2 } != $LocalBlock { 3 * $i + 2 }
                            ) {
                                    return ( 0 );
                    }
            }

            return ( 1 );
    }
    /*
    :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    ::
    ::      GIFWord...
    ::
    */
    function GIFWord ( $int ) {

            return ( chr ( $int & 0xFF ) . chr ( ( $int >> 8 ) & 0xFF ) );
    }
    /*
    :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
    ::
    ::      GetAnimation...
    ::
    */
    function GetAnimation ( ) {
            return ( $this->GIF );
    }
}
```

Comment: This post's kinda old, but I think it's worth noting to anyone that finds this that the GIFEncoder.Class.php Posted by Danny is V3.00.  if you have a lower version than 3.00, the solution provided will not work. Additionally, copy and pasting the class from THIS page will cause errors. So you will have to Google the updated class. Good Luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution... Just set the loop to False

Answer (score 0):

This class has mistake. Please replace all '**$$this->OFS**' to '**$this->OFS**'

```
$gif = new GIFEncoder (

    // 1. frames
    array('1.gif', '2.gif', '3.gif'), 

    // 2. speed - array for frames or number
    //array(500,500,500),
    20,

    // 3. loops - number or false
    0,

    // 4. disposal ??? - what is it?
    2,

    // 5-7. transparent RGB
    0,0,0,

    // 8. padding array with point(x,y) or 0
    array(
        array(0,50),
        array(0,0)
    ),

    // 9. source 'url' or 'bin'
    "url"
);
```